# Problem with Font in iPad application

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, fonts, uiwebview

In a UIWebView of my iPad application, I display a HTML file with a Cambria font (the font type is set in a css file). This font is not supposed to work on iPad but the font that appeared seemed nice to me.

Now I'm trying to use the same font in the rest of my application and I discovered that Cambria font is not available on iPad.

Do you know what font the system is using to replace Cambria in my WebView ? I looked in the [list of available font for iPad](http://www.michaelcritz.com/2010/04/02/fonts-for-ipad-iphone/), but I found nothing close to the font I have in my webview.

I really would like to get the same font in the rest of my application.

Here is how the font looks like :
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e10d1986d5.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e10d1986d5.png)

Comment: Are you testing on the device or simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a screenshot from the iPad (Home button + Shutdown button) and upload it to the [What The Font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) site.

This site can scan the image and tell what font is used in it.

Comment: Thanks that did it ! 
The automatic system of the web site didn't find the solution, but a "human expert" on the site find the correct font : TimesNewRomanPSMT